# Burninate [c-like]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [c-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-like) tag currently has 14 questions under it, it appears that several of these questions are off topic entirely, several should have been tagged instead with a specific language tag instead of the vague [c-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-like) tag and several others seem to have the tag for no reason and do not really benefit from it.

The term c-like isn't particularly well defined and would seem to promote vague questions which are not appropriate for stack overflow.

I think this tag should not exist and should potentially be replaced with some more specific language tags where appropriate.

with regards to the tag removal guideline, I would say this tag:

- Does not have the same meaning in all cases, in some cases it is with regards to a C like calling convention, in some about a c like language or a language with some c like syntax forms or features and in some discusses c vs c++ best practices
- Is often ambiguous and doesn't help describe the questions. One cannot reasonably be an expert in "c-like"

Comment: Supported, there's not even a tag wiki.

Comment: I have removed the tag from all that questionsquestions now.

Comment: *How shall we turn this title into a pun?*

Comment: @James_Parsons "Un-like [c-like]"

Comment: "double-plus-un-like" has better scansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag was removed from the afflicted questions by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96) according to his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300777/burninate-c-like?lq=1#comment228759_300777), so this question can be and should be closed — the tag [c-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-like) has been incinerated because, as you can see, we collectively dislike the tag.

In some ways, it is sad this question will continue to exist to immortalize the otherwise forgettable, but removing the tag makes a mild improvement to the site.