# Why isn't providing a minimal tag-wiki mandatory, when new tags are created?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

Question is pretty much as stated in the title:

Why isn't providing a minimal tag-wiki mandatory, when new tags are created?

There's a number of unclear tags around like the one mentioned in this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300777/burninate-c-like). Many of them may be even have been created by mistake.

If a new tag is created, the process should ask the poster giving a minimal description of that new tag. Like the minimum 20 characters required for the summary when writing a new tag-wiki. The summary may just be replicated in the long description body at this point.

Comment: My guess is that this isn't mandatory because at that point the person is trying to ask a question. Creating a tag is secondary. It might be worth a try, though. It would at least be interesting to see how many people will take the time to write something meaningful.

Comment: @BilltheLizard _"... how many people will take the time to write something meaningful."_ I hope for better stuff as _asdfassdfassdfassdfasddfvasdff_ actually ;-).

Comment: Good enough for a first draft. :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Doesn't the SE engine already have some filters that would deny something like that as a question/answer body?

Comment: There are filters, but I think they're looking for more specific things. Keyboard mashing can produce any random text, so it's hard to find a pattern that would reliably match it.

Comment: What do you do if the wiki gets rejected?  Does the next time someone uses the tag they have to provide a wiki, do we leave it be, blow away the tag and wait fore another try?

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point. Though the rejection could remove the invalid tag from that post, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm sure you could I just didn't know how you would want it handled in the case the edit was rejected.

Comment: I would guess that an awful lot of new tags are created by new-ish users, do we really want them creating the tag and writing the wiki? Then again, it may be easier to spot bad tags by their bad tag wikis...

Comment: @apaul34208 We don't want them getting through posting their question and create a new unsolic unsolicited tag along

Comment: I would have thought the [1500 reputation privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) would have warded off a lot of really bad tags.  But I guess not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*Why?*

Because doing it right would be hard.

We seriously considered implementing [Promote tag wiki creation for new tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129624/promote-tag-wiki-creation-for-new-tags) back in May of 2014, but couldn't come up with a UX that wasn't complicated. So we went with [Warning or confirmation on new tag creation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation) instead, hoping that simply warning tag-creators against using new tags would suffice to discourage abuse.

I *still* think this would be a good idea, but it's gonna take someone having serious time to sit down and work out all the fiddly bits (conflicting permissions, what to do with tags when the wiki edit is rejected because the author got confused and copied his question into it, etc.) to make it happen.

Comment: I'm a little confused. (That happens very easily.) Do you mean promoting wiki creating is a good idea, or do you mean requiring a minimal one is a good idea? (I think the former.)

Comment: Maybe that confirmation popup should explicitly suggest creating a tag wiki/excerpt for the new tag?

Comment: I would think that after posting the question the user is simply redirected to the tag wiki editor, with a helpful message "You created a new tag with your question, please fill in some detail, etc. etc."

Answer (score 10):

Writing a brand-new wiki from scratch, even an excerpt, is actually quite hard. All, or nearly all, of my attempts to do so have been rejected on various sites for various reasons*… compared to less than 60 out of my other nearly 900 edit suggestions. Admittedly, the rejection rate might improve if reviewers had more experience, but the flood of low-quality wikis would probably just give broken windows the predominant effect, such that bad wikis would be approved along with good ones, or either quality rejected, without any coherent reason for either outcome.

Worse, a good excerpt usually has coalesces around guidance for what the tag should be, and should not be, used for… which is best understood when a tag actually has some genuine usage already. A few dozen questions, or even a few hundred.

Finally, the guidance for writing wikis from scratch is fairly minimal even now, so it's not like you can just point people at a set of straightforward good examples and say "there!" (I've looked.)

So requiring any old new-tag-creator to write something up that is Hard with a capital H, and prematurely at that, just does not seem practical, and the result would be poorer-quality wikis and inferior tag categorization in general. This is not a good idea.

<sub>**Some plausible, and some much less so.*</sub>

Comment: My point is just preventing from newly added tags, not how to write good tsg- wiki's!

Comment: So, you don't actually want any new tags at all? My answer here is stating that, because nearly all the tag wikis that would be created because of this would be terrible, this is a bad idea.

Comment: Specifically, would you prefer to forbid questions about languages or libraries created after July 2015?

Comment: @tepples: Not sure πάντα ῥεῖ will get notified for that comment....

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So the asker isn't notified of comments on answers?