# What is the most appropriate way for a user with lower reputation to request a new tag?

Tags: support, tag-creation-process

I spend a fair bit of time working with small projects on SO. Sometimes the project begins with a beta name and that name changes once a release candidate is finalized. I feel that product name changes would generally be considered a "strong case" as outlined in the [tag help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

> Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new
>   tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question
>   covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this
>   site.

<del>What</del> Where is the best way outlined to request a new tag be created and present the "strong case"  <del>for users with under 1500 reputation</del>  ? Is this topic appropriate to be included in the wiki or help center?

<del>On suggestion based on the discussion in the question:
[Why isn't providing a minimal tag-wiki mandatory, when new tags are created?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300778/why-isnt-providing-a-minimal-tag-wiki-mandatory-when-new-tags-are-created)
Would changing privileges to allow new tag creation above 100 reputation but require tag wikis be a feasible workaround?</del>

Comment: I think the situation is that if you don't have the reputation, you can post your proposal here and hope someone else picks up on it. Alternatively, you wait until you earn the reputation.

Comment: If that is the current best practice should the tag help center be updated to direct users to follow those guidelines?

Comment: @rene I am aware of that fact. Like I stated in the question, I am asking since a collection of questions exist under a tag created for a beta name. The beta name is no longer used and those questions along with any future questions should be moved to a new tag which does not yet exist.

Comment: OK, I don't think the procedure is any different from the current answer or the proposed duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tag can't just be created; it has to be attached to an existing question.*

**If the question has been posted:** Follow the guidance in the FAQ entry "[When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/2738262)". Plead the case for a new tag [in a comment on the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117287/how-can-i-create-a-new-tag-when-i-dont-have-the-privilege-to-do-so/134893#134893) or in an active related chat room. Or if the tag needs a lot of justification, or if you want to draft the tag wiki, request the new tag in a question here on Meta Stack Overflow.

**If the missing tag is blocking posting a question:**
If answers to [What tag to use for question in a new programming language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283027/what-tag-to-use-for-question-in-a-new-programming-language) are any indication, you can add a second-best tag, such as a platform, language, or subject tag, or perhaps the previous name of the project, so that the question at least gets posted. Then ask for the new tag, as described above.

In a comment to your question, you clarified that several questions already exist with the old tag. So perhaps a question on Meta Stack Overflow with the tag [retag-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request) would be the better choice.

<sub>* You might notice a bootstrap problem here. The first tags on Stack Overflow or each other Stack Exchange site were created during private beta when "create tags" required 1 reputation.</sub>

Comment: Is this the recommended practice? Did I miss the instructions in the wiki or help center or should these instructions be added to the help center?

Comment: @Nathan The Help Center can't be modified on individual sites except for the on-topic page. Questions tagged `faq` Meta Stack Exchange and on child metas extend the . The part about questions that have already been posted largely restates [the FAQ about tag creation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/2738262).

Comment: The FAQ is helpful in understanding the whys and your updated answer helps point out the proper how for tagging on Meta. The tag creation question does seem to crop up on Meta regularly. Perhaps a better question is how to make the FAQ and recommended practices a little easier to find.